# Nokogiri How can I extract text from HTML with correct spacing?

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to extract the text for a document to index it for search. The below mostly works except various words and punctuation run together. When it removes tags, I need to replace them with spaces so I do not get this issue. I have been trying to figure out the most efficient way to do this but I'm coming up empty so far.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.xpath("//script").remove
doc.xpath("//style").remove
doc.xpath("//a").remove
text = doc.text.gsub(/\s+/,' ')
```

Here is some sample text I extracted from http://www.washingtontimes.com/blog/redskins-watch/2012/oct/18/redskins-linemen-respond-jason-pierre-paul-rg3-com/

> Before the season it was New York Giants defensive end Osi Umenyiora
>   who made waves by saying he wouldn't call Robert Griffin III by “RG3”
>   until he did something. Until then, it was “Bob Griffin.”After
>   Griffin's 76-yard touchdown run in the Washington Redskins' victory
>   over the Minnesota Vikings, fellow Giants defensive end Jason
>   Pierre-Paul was the one who had some comments about Griffin.“Don’t
>   bring it to my side," Pierre-Paul told New York media. “Go the other
>   way. …“Yes, it'll be a very good matchup. Not on my side, though. Not
>   on my side. Or the other side.”Griffin, asked jokingly Wednesday about
>   running for office, said: “I’ve got a lot other guys to be running
>   away from right now, Pierre-Paul, Osi, all those guys.”But according
>   to a couple of Redskins linemen, Griffin shouldn't have much to worry
>   about Sunday if he gets into the open field.“If Robert gets into that
>   situation, I don't think there's many people that can run him down,”
>   right guard Chris Chester said. “I'm still going to go out there and
>   try to block and make sure no one touches Robert at all. But he's a
>   plenty good athlete to be able to outrun a lot of people in this
>   league.”Prompted with Pierre-Paul's comments, left tackle Trent
>   Williams responded: “What do you want me to say about that?”“Robert's
>   my guy. I don't know Pierre-Paul. I don't know why he would say
>   something like that,” he said. “Maybe he knows something I don't.”

Comment: Don't include a link to the sample text, instead, include a sample of the HTML itself. If that link breaks your question will be worthless to future searches by people looking for the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try inserting a space before each p tag:

```
doc.search('p').each{|el| el.before ' '}
```

but a better approach probably is something like:

```
text = doc.search('div.story p').map{|p| p.text}.join(" ")
```

Comment: I think the first is close to what I need.  Is there a way to by default to this to every node and not just the p tags?  I'm scraping from thousands of sources so I'll hit more than this tag with this issue.

Comment: You'd could use something like 'body *' instead of 'p'

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are discussing inserting whitespace into the document, but if (as the question asks) your requirement is to *replace* those nodes with whitespace, Nokogiri has a replace method. So to replace script tags with spaces do:

```
doc.xpath('//script').each do |node|
  node.replace(' ') 
end
```

The question also asks about 'correct' spacing. Most browsers will not insert a space when they render around a `<script>` tag, so while useful for text extraction, this is not necessarily the 'correct' thing to do.